# Mixing FirebaseUI CDN with NPM managament

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, astrojs

Looking for the best way to mix npm and FirebaseUI with i18n.

I have Firebase libraries in the project and I want to keep its management under `npm`.
But FirebaseUI is not ready to use `npm` in other language than English.

So to use different languages, I need to import it via CDN.

I'm trying to figure out how to load FirebaseUI from CDN, but still using the compat libraries using `npm`.

Next, version working using only CDN and version failing to mix with `npm`.

Working version using CDN to load firebase libraries:

```html
<script is:inline src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

<script>
    import firebaseConfig from 'js/firebase_config';

    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const uiConfig = {
       .......
    };

    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

But this code throws an error:

```html
<script is:inline src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

<script>
    import firebaseConfig from 'js/firebase_config';
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
    import 'firebase/compat/auth';

    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const uiConfig = {
       .......
    };

    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

Error:

```
firebase-ui-auth__es.js:422 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at new Dn (firebase-ui-auth__es.js:422:1944)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding ***`window.firebase = firebase;`*** is fixing the problem, but is this the way?

> Note: Still a question pending: why it's not working without this workaround? I'm open to mark other answer as valid if it its response with a reason about why this.

Working mixing:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

<script>
    import firebaseConfig from 'js/firebase_config';
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
    import 'firebase/compat/auth';

    // Fix firebaseUI not finding the firebase instance.
    window.firebase = firebase;

    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const uiConfig = {
       .......
    };

    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```